# Where does Google Drive save notes on sharing invitations?

Tags: google-drive

When I share an item from Google Drive I have the option to "Add a note" to the recipient (see screenshot below).  After I send that invitation, where is that note saved?

(It is included in an email to the share recipient, but I can't find it in my GMail Sent Mail.)

[image: Google Drive Share dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Drive doesn't save the notes in a user reachable repository. If you want to keep the note, you should click the "Advanced" link shown on your screenshot on the bottom-right corner, then tick the "Send a copy to my self" checkbox.

[image]